# Twisted Day convolution

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Has anyone studied a version of [Day convolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution) for an enriched presheaf category $V^{A^{\mathrm{op}}}$ where the monoidal structure of $V$ is "twisted" on one side by an action of $A$?  I'm thinking of modifying the standard formula

$$(F \otimes G)(a) = \int^{b,c} F(b)\otimes G(c) \otimes A(b\otimes c,a)$$

to something like

$$(F \otimes G)(a) = \int^{b,c} F(b)\otimes G(c)^b \otimes A(b\otimes c,a)$$

where $G(c)^b$ denotes an action of $b\in A$ on $G(c)\in V$.

Comment: Sorry for the trivial request of clarification, but I can't interpret the notion of action of an object $b\in A$ on $Gc$ in $\cal V$...

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I mean that $A$ acts on $V$ by a functor $A\times V\to V$, say, whose action is written $(b,X) \mapsto X^b$.

Comment: Now I understand better; but I'm still stuck in proving that $(F,G)\mapsto F\otimes G$ is associative (a strange isomorphism between coends, namely
$$
\int^x A(z\cdot t, x)^u\otimes A(u\cdot x, a)\cong A(u\cdot z\cdot t, a)
$$
must hold. I'm not able to prove or disprove it (it's a "twisted ninja Yoneda lemma").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a proof that the twisted monoidal structure $\otimes^\rho$ is a convolution on $[A, V]$, where $A$ is a monoidal category, $V$ the cosmos on which $A$ is enriched, and $\rho\colon A\times V\to V$ a *monoidal action* (in the sense that $(v^a)^b \cong v^{a\cdot b}$, $v^i \cong v$ where $i$ is the monoidal identity of $A$, and $(v\otimes w)^a \cong v^a \otimes w^a$).

To make things work, I must assume that

1. Every object $a$ of the monoidal structure $(A, \cdot, i)$ has a monoidal inverse $a^{-1}$;
2. The functor $(-)^a \colon V\to V$ is cocontinuous.

This is somehow restricive, but since we know ([coends](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503), Prop. A.3) that (strong) promonoidal structure in $C$ correspond bijectively with convolution structures on $[A, V]$, there must exist a convolution product such that
$$
F\otimes^\rho G \cong \int^{xy} Fx \otimes Gy \otimes P_\rho(x,y;-)
$$
so that the action $(x,y)\mapsto (Gy)^x$ is "absorbed" into the promonoidal functor $P\colon A^\text{op}\times A^\text{op} \times A \to V$.

I'm not able to find the $P_\rho$, but I'm able to find sufficient assumptions (those above) to ensure associativity. As I mentioned in the comment, I come up with a "twisted ninja Yoneda lemma" ([coends](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503), Prop. 2.1), and I learned something more about coend-nonsense, so thank you (-:

Let's start the coend-juggling:
\begin{align}
[(F \otimes^\rho G)\otimes^\rho H](a) &= \int^{bc} (F\otimes^\rho G)(b)\otimes (Hc)^b \otimes A(b\cdot c, a) \\
 & \cong \int^{bcxy} Fx \otimes (Gy)^x \otimes A(x\cdot y, b)\otimes (Hc)^b \otimes A(b\cdot c, a) \\
 & \cong \int^{bcxy} Fx \otimes (Gy)^x \otimes (Hc)^b \otimes A(x\cdot y, b)\otimes A(b\cdot c, a) \\
 & \cong \int^{cxy}Fx \otimes (Gy)^x \otimes \left( \int^b (Hc)^b \otimes A(x\cdot y, b)\otimes A(b\cdot c, a) \right) \\
 & \cong \int^{cxy}Fx \otimes (Gy)^x \otimes (Hc)^{x \cdot y}\otimes A((x\cdot y)\cdot c, a)
\end{align}
where I applied the ninja Yoneda lemma to the functor $S(b) = (Hc)^b \otimes A(b\cdot c, a)$ ($S$ results as the composition $b\overset{\Delta}\mapsto (b,b) \overset{\hat S}\mapsto (Hc)^b \otimes A(b\cdot c, a)$; this type of dependence is essential, and implicit in the definition). We now have to manipulate the other parenthesization of $F,G,H$: to obtain the same object, we need the assumptions of cocompleteness of the action and invertibility:
\begin{align}
[F \otimes^\rho (G\otimes^\rho H)](a) & \cong \int^{mn} Fm \otimes ((G\otimes^\rho H)(n))^m \otimes A(m\cdot n, a) \\
& \cong \int^{mnzt} Fm \otimes \Big( Gz\otimes (Ht)^z \otimes A(z\cdot t, n)\Big)^m \otimes A(m\cdot n, a) \\
& \cong \int^{mnzt} Fm \otimes (Gz)^m \otimes (Ht)^{z\cdot m} \otimes A(z\cdot t, n)^m \otimes A(m\cdot n, a) \\
& \cong \int^{mzt} Fm \otimes (Gz)^m \otimes (Ht)^{z\cdot m} \otimes \left( \int^n A(z\cdot t, n)^m \otimes A(m\cdot n, a) \right)\\
& \cong \int^{mzt} Fm \otimes (Gz)^m \otimes (Ht)^{z\cdot m} \otimes \left( \int^n A(z\cdot t, n) \otimes A(m\cdot n, a)^{m^{-1}} \right)^m\\
& \cong \int^{mzt} Fm \otimes (Gz)^m \otimes (Ht)^{z\cdot m} \otimes \Big( A(m\cdot (z\cdot t), a)^{m^{-1}} \Big)^m\\
& \cong \int^{mzt} Fm \otimes (Gz)^m \otimes (Ht)^{z\cdot m} \otimes A(m\cdot (z\cdot t), a)
\end{align}
where I applied the assumptions, and the ninja Yoneda lemma.

The same manipulations show that the presheaf $\hom(i,-)$ is the monoidal unit.
\begin{align}
F \otimes^\rho I & = \int^{bc} Fb \otimes A(i,c)^b \otimes A(b\cdot c ,a ) \\
& \cong \int^b Fb \otimes \left( \int^c A(i,c) \otimes A(b\cdot c, a)^{b^{-1}} \right)^b \\
&\cong \cdots
\end{align}

Comment: Not bad.  I don't think there's any reason to put "ninja" in front of "Yoneda lemma", though (although the versions you're using here are, I think, more commonly known as the co-Yoneda lemma, since we're tensoring with a presheaf instead of mapping out of it).  Also, I think your assumption (2) follows from your assumption (1): if every object has an inverse, then $(-)^a$ is an equivalence of categories, hence cocontinuous.  Finally, you can deduce $P_\rho$ from a monoidal structure on the presheaf category just by tensoring representables (but the answer may not be illuminating).

Comment: Actually, I just realized that your assumptions, together with the implicit assumptions in the question, trivialize the whole situation, because the only V-enriched automorphism of V is the identity!  However, all is not lost, because in the example I'm interested in, the action of A on V (though indeed invertible, as you assumed) is not a V-functor, and the resulting convolution structure is not a V-monoidal category; so it can be nontrivial, and I think your calculations still work formally in that case.

Comment: You're right about cocontinuity. Hmm, i didn't know that "the only V-enriched automorphism of V is the identity", is it something trivial or needs a proof?

Comment: A V-enriched equivalence is, as noted, necessarily V-cocontinuous.  But every object X of V is the X-weighted colimit of the unit object.

Comment: Ah!  And if you drop $V$-enrichedness of $A$, then you don't need invertibility of the action any more, since $\otimes A(z\cdot t,n)$ is now just a copower, hence preserved (without needing to twist the mere set $A(z\cdot t,n)$) by the cocontinuous functor $(-)^m$.